# How do i write a code to dynamically create a <span element with the name of the image when the showpic function is executed?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm quite new to coding and functions etc. I've decided to look for online exam papers so I can learn from them questions and one of them says...

> Write the code to dynamically create a  element with the name of the image file when the showpic unction is executed. For example if the name of the image file is images/image1.jpg then the dynamically created element should be images/image1.jpg

and the code i am looking at is...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>CI135</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1>CI135</h1>
                <h2>1: JavaScript image gallery</h2>
            </header>
            <ul id="images">
                <li>
                    <a href="images/image1.jpg" title="Fruit">
                        <img src="images/image1.jpg" class="thumb" alt="Fruit" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="images/image2.jpg" title="Flowers">
                    <img src="images/image2.jpg" class="thumb" alt="Flowers"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
                </ul>
                <figure>
                <img id="place" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Image of fruit" />
                    <figcaption id="description">Fruit</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <span id="placeholder"></span>
                <footer>&copy; CI135 teaching team, 2013-2014</footer>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: have you some questions related to the code?

Comment: What's your problem? It seems that's all right

Comment: I'm not sure as I am new to this so i do not understand this fully. There is another code that I look at as well so maybe I've shown you guys the wrong one. I will edit the code onto the main question above.

Comment: please also add script.js file in your question

Comment: it will be better if you add jsfiddle link here

Answer (score 1):

We're definitely not a "gimme-codez" type of site, but we could get you going in the right direction.

HTML is not a "dynamic" language -- what you see in the code is how it evaluates.  A table is a table, and it'll only have as many rows as you put in it, for example.

What the question is asking is to create a function, likely Javascript, that will allow you to pass a value, likely a file path, and have it render a span containing the image, with any values desired.

So, you'd be looking to do something along these lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createSpan(file) {
       return '<span id="file"><img src="/path/to/'+file+'"></span>';
    }
</script>
```

I highly recommend reading basic tutorials on Javascript to get yourself up to speed on it.  In a nutshell, a function can be used to repeat tasks, returning outcomes you can use inside your code.